# How do i search for words in my text column? mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, persistence

I have a column in my table which is of type `text`. The user may type any combination of words , it should appear  in the result. Eg. Suppose string is :- `Addicted to stackoverflow`

And suppose user types `addicted` and `stackoverflow`, then also results should appear. In other words, it is not a simple `like` operator through which we can get results. Other option is to use Full Text Search. But my table is InnoDb and not MyISAM, so I can't use even Full Text Search. I will have to make a temporary table each time some user searches for a string. This is terribly inefficient.

Can anybody tell me any other approach that may work out for me? If anybody has their own algorithm then also please share it. I will better go with that rather than creating temporary tables and dropping them each time some search is made.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.sphinxsearch.com/ or http://lucene.apache.org/ or MySQL's `RLIKE` function

Answer (score 1):

[Sphinxsearch](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) actually supports InnoDB, as well as MyISAM.